# Share Point Client Object Model - UndoCheckOut did not work

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I am trying to Discard Check Out on a specific Checked Out Share Point file but I got stuck.

Here is my code snippet:

```
//Define a ClientContext with the specific Share Point site Url.
var ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
var folder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl);

//Get specific folder`s Url, where the target file exists.
ctx.Load(folder, f => f.ServerRelativeUrl);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

//Get file`s data.
var targetFileName = "someFile.txt";
var file = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(folder.ServerRelativeUrl + targetFileName);
ctx.Load(file, f => f.Exists, f => f.Name);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

//Output file data to ensure that we got exactly that file. That WriteLine provides required output without any errors.
Console.WriteLine($"File Data\n--> Exists: {file.Exists}\n--> Name: {file.Name}");


//Try to Undo Check Out. DID NOT WORK ??? File is checked out 100500%!
file.UndoCheckOut();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

The problem is that when I`m trying to execute the UndoCheckOut method - it throws the following kind of exception:

*Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: The file "cst/PTFixLists/RPA_Robot testing folder/Combined Fix list and Manual Errors 5-14-18 2.xlsx" is not checked out.*

I appreciate any help!

Have a great day!

Comment: It didn't work because the file wasn't checked out to begin with. There's no call to `File.CheckOut()` in the code you posted

Comment: It has been checked out by a particular user with help of Share Point SIte UI (web-browser) and I`m trying to do the Undo Check Out. All required permissions and rights were provided to that account.

Comment: The error says it's *not* checked out. Check through the UI again. Check whether the file is checked out in your code too, before calling `UndoCheckOut()`.

Comment: Could you check if you can UndoCheckOut using this code with a file that you have checked out yourself (as in the account that is running the code)?

Comment: check File CheckOutType Property and see if you can check in file or not. do you control on file and  version setting is proper or not.

Comment: Regarding the @PanagiotisKanavos `s answer.
I have tried to do the CheckOut on the file, but got next error:

_Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: The URL 'cst/PTFixLists/RPA_Robot testing folder/data.txt' is invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web._

I don`t understand why. This file`s ServerRelative URL is definitely OK because I have retrieved proper information about it.

Comment: @PedroLorentz, no I don`t (

Comment: @JayneshSharma, yes I have full control and owner`s rights on that Share Point folder.

Comment: @A.Dovbysh You haven't really explained what you did or how the doc library/file are configured. `It works from the UI` doesn't mean much - there may be an automatic checkout rule, there may be a trigger or workflow that modifies the checkout state. Or the file may have versioning enabled, in which case trying to modify it generates a minor version and checkout is only available to the editor, for that minor version. You're trying to emulate what SharePoint's own workflow and actions do. Well, you need to really understand how versioning, checkin/checkout, sites etc work

Comment: At least post what SharePoint version you use (full version numbers), whether it's local or Online. What are the versioning settings for the library? What *exactly* are you trying to do? Not `I want to check in`, but `I want to check in any files checked out by *another* user 10 hours after they saved them last time`. It could be that you can't see the changes to unpublished drafts. `I have permission` won't let you see *drafts*, if the library is configured to hide them unless published. That's not a permission setting.

Comment: @A.Dovbysh that said, there's a reason experienced SharePoint developers know the maximum age limit for joining the Foreign Legion. The product is a beast that's only really tested along the happy path. *Something* in *your* installation, *your* library may be broken. Or a particular sequence of actions didn't go well with some particular patch, leaving the site in a strange state.

Comment: @A.Dovbysh try in different  library where its just OOTB library.

In the SharePoint ribbon, in the Library tab, select the Library Settings button in the Settings area. In the settings page, under the General Settings header, you'll see Versioning settings. Here, you can select settings for versioning, and if you configure the Library to support versioning the code will work.
 Major and Minor versioning is enabled or not ?.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the file has been checkedout in the code snippet to avoid the error in the question:

```
    //Define a ClientContext with the specific Share Point site Url.
    var siteUrl="http://sp/sites/devtest";
    var folderUrl="/sites/devtest/Shared%20Documents";
    var ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var folder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl);

    //Get specific folder`s Url, where the target file exists.
    ctx.Load(folder, f => f.ServerRelativeUrl);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    //Get file`s data.
    var targetFileName = "dsc_0520.jpg";
    var file = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(folder.ServerRelativeUrl +"/" +targetFileName);
    ctx.Load(file, f => f.Exists, f => f.Name,f=>f.CheckOutType);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    //Output file data to ensure that we got exactly that file. That WriteLine provides required output without any errors.
    Console.WriteLine("File Data\n--> Exists: {0}\n--> Name: {1}",file.Exists,file.Name);


    //Try to Undo Check Out if the file.CheckOutType==CheckOutType.Online is true
    if(file.CheckOutType==CheckOutType.Online)
    {
        file.UndoCheckOut();
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
```

I tested in my side, it's working to UnDo CheckOut for the CheckedOut files.

Comment: Hello and thank you!
I have tried to do so, but an error still exists :(

Comment: Please try to upload a new txt file for a UnDoCheckOut() test, this is working in my side.

Comment: And please make sure the file relative url in  ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl is valid one, in the error message, it specify the file is Excel xslx file

Comment: Well, I tried to use another file for a test. That`s why we have an Excel file in the Exception message. But the problem is the same in both cases.

Comment: How about checkin/out from UI ? Did it work for the target file used in the code ?

Comment: When I am using UI - everything works fine. I need to implement such approach with help of CSOM :)

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in the question in my side. I will check again tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

@JayneshSharma, I have attached settings via a screenshot. Please, take a look)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKZFb.png)